# Notation of an Algebra over the Real Numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

A vector space $A$, over a field $K$, equipped with a bilinear map $m: A \times A \to A$ is defined as an algebra (or an algebra over a field).

In many books and articles, the most interesting case is when $K = \mathbb{R}$.

My question is: is there a notation or a special name for algebras over $\mathbb{R}$? We cannot say that the algebra is real because this definition is about a $\ast$-algebra $A$ where $a^{\ast} = a$, $\forall\ a \in A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}$-algebra.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field

> An algebra over K is sometimes also called a K-algebra